# Delete child item inside ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to add an remove function on my child list inside ExpandableListView, but when I clicked the button inside child list, it always returns me the last list on my child even though I select the first one or other child list.

Here's my source code for ExpandableListView

ExpandableListView Code :

```
 private void fillData(){
        String COA = String.format(dataBaseHelper.getCount(VisitDate));
        if(COA.equals(0)) {
            mGroupsCursor = dataBaseHelper.getSelectedParentMVPDate(reformatMVPDate());
            startManagingCursor(mGroupsCursor);
            mGroupsCursor.moveToFirst();
            ExpandableListView SelectedListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.MVPListitem);
            mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(mGroupsCursor, this,
                    R.layout.mvp_list_parent,
                    R.layout.mvp_list_child,
                    new String[]{DataBaseHelper.MVP_INDUSTRY_TYPE},
                    new int[]{R.id.txtMVPParent},
                    new String[]{DataBaseHelper.MVP_BRCH_CODE_NAME, DataBaseHelper.MVP_BRCH_ADDRESS, DataBaseHelper.MVP_ID},
                    new int[]{R.id.txtviewBrnchCodeName, R.id.txtviewBrchAddr, R.id.txtmvpID});
            SelectedListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
        else{
            mGroupsCursor = dataBaseHelper.getSelectedParentMVPDate(reformatMVPDate());
            startManagingCursor(mGroupsCursor);
            mGroupsCursor.moveToFirst();
            ExpandableListView SelectedListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.MVPListitem);
            mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(mGroupsCursor, this,
                    R.layout.mvp_list_parent,
                    R.layout.mvp_list_child,
                    new String[]{DataBaseHelper.MVP_INDUSTRY_TYPE},
                    new int[]{R.id.txtMVPParent},
                    new String[]{DataBaseHelper.MVP_BRCH_CODE_NAME, DataBaseHelper.MVP_BRCH_ADDRESS, DataBaseHelper.MVP_ID},
                    new int[]{R.id.txtviewBrnchCodeName, R.id.txtviewBrchAddr, R.id.txtmvpID});
            SelectedListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }

    public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {
        public MyExpandableListAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context,int groupLayout,
                                       int childLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom,
                                       int[] childrenTo) {
            super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
                    childLayout, childrenFrom, childrenTo);
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            @SuppressLint("Range") Cursor childCursor = dataBaseHelper.getSelectedChildMVPDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.MVP_INDUSTRY_TYPE)),reformatMVPDate());
            startManagingCursor(childCursor);
            childCursor.moveToFirst();
            return childCursor;
        }

        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition,
                                 final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
                                 ViewGroup parent) {


    View rowView = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition,
                    isLastChild, convertView, parent);




            removeMVP = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
            txtBCN = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtviewBrnchCodeName);
            txtBA = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtviewBrchAddr);
            txtmvpID = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtmvpID);
            if(edit.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                removeMVP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                removeMVP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //remove childList
            removeMVP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("Range")
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MasterVisitPlan.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Delete Appointment")
                            .setMessage("Are you sure? Assigned date and branch will be removed." + txtBCN.getText().toString())
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Cursor res = dataBaseHelper.getCounterVisitData(txtBCN.getText().toString(), reformatDate());
                                    if(res.getCount() == 0){
                                        return;
                                    }while (res.moveToNext()){
                                        ctrVisit = res.getString(3);
                                    }
                                    int diffCounterVisit = Integer.parseInt(ctrVisit) - 1;
                                    dataBaseHelper.updateCounterVisit(txtBCN.getText().toString(),String.valueOf(diffCounterVisit),reformatDate());
                                    Integer deletedRows = dataBaseHelper.DeleteSelectedChildMVPDate(txtmvpID.getText().toString());
                                    if(deletedRows > 0){
                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MasterVisitPlan.this);
                                        builder.setMessage("✔ Successfully removed.")
                                                .setCancelable(false)
                                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                        edit.clearAnimation();
                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                        setMonthView();
                                                        getStatus();
                                                        btnViewfromUploadStatus();
                                                        enableView(calendar, false);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                        AlertDialog dialogDeleted = builder.create();
                                        dialogDeleted.show();
                                    }else{
                                        Toast.makeText(MasterVisitPlan.this, "Data not Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    fillData();
                                    countMVPData();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you have to replace `while (res.moveToNext()){ ctrVisit = res.getString(3); }` with some code related to **childPosition**.

Comment: Thank you sir. Everything is fine now, The problem is I declared my button and textviews as Global.